# How to call button or cast onItemClickListener in a different fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

> I have been searching for this for days and to no avail whatsoever. I have the following problem: I have a MainActivity which is mostly indiferent to this problem. Inside this main activity I have a fragment. This fragment holds a viewpager whose element is also a fragment. Now, I have a button declared in the viewpager fragment layout, which I would like to call in the "parent" fragment. Any ideas???
>
> Now, moving on to what I have already tried. I have tried to call directly, then I tried to declare an OnClickListener inside either fragment, and I also tried to use callbaciks. However none of these solutions worked...
>
> I have tons of code useless to you, so I will only highlight the important parts
>
> Parent Fragment (ScheduleFragment)

```
button_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Are you Sure?")
                        .setMessage("There's no coming back!")
                        .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                            }
                        })
                        .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                deleteThis(viewPager2.getCurrentItem());
                                SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor sEditor = preferences.edit();
                                Integer position = preferences.getInt("Number of Days", 3) + 1;
                                sEditor.putInt("Number of Days", position);
                                sEditor.apply();
                            }
                        });
                builder.show();
            }
        });
```

My Child Fragment (ViewPager_ScheduleObject

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_viewpager_schedule))
                .setText("Day " + args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT));

        ViewPager2_Schedule_Adapter viewPager2_schedule_adapter= new ViewPager2_Schedule_Adapter(this);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        Button button_cancel = view.findViewById(R.id.button_cancel_day);
        button_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
```

> If you need any more code, be sure to let me know! Any help is apprecciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Interface,  Make Something Like this

```
   public interface OurClient {
            public void myButton(View view);

   }
```

then Implement the interface in your main class

Comment: For anyone coming back to this post for help don't forget to attach the fragment inside the other's fragment (onCreateView in my case)! Do it like such: @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(@NonNull Fragment childFragment) {
        super.onAttachFragment(childFragment);
        if (childFragment instanceof ViewPager_Schedule_Object) {
            ViewPager_Schedule_Object headlinesFragment = (ViewPager_Schedule_Object) childFragment;
            headlinesFragment.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        }
    }